# Riddle? Word Game

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Mark? Take aim
>
> Action? Misnamed
>
> Usage? Explain
>
> Replace? Fair game

Hint:

> Crohn's? Inflamed

Hint 2:

> Research the first hint maybe?

Hint for line 2:

> it's referring to a person.

Comment: Confused? Same.

Comment: Answer? Still can't. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proposed answer

> Replace the ? With a colon : on the strength of replace fair game and crohns inflamed.

So 1

> Mark: Take aim.  Colon is a punctuation mark and concentrates attention

2

> Action: Misnamed.  It is kind of yes but not really a Riddle: Word game.  Or, instead of a question and answer, each line is now an imperative statement.

3

> Usage: Explain.  Yes, this is what I am doing now.

4

> Replace: Fair game. Thank you for the permission!

Hint 1

> Crohn's: Inflamed.  Because Crohn's is colon inflammation.

I got nothing for hint 2

Comment: Your answer is correct! The intended explanation for hint 3 is that rot13(lbh bsgra hfr n pbyba gb rkcynva jung pbzrf nsgre), and for hint 2, perhaps rot13(guvax bs n qvssrerag glcr bs pbyba)

Comment: For closure, note that 2 is rot13(Cristobal Colon, who thought he had discovered Indians)